# How do I Build A .json Endpoint with a Sequelize Query?

Tags: rest, express, sequelize.js

Struggling to get my head around this for a week and a half, I was wondering how to get a .json endpoint that is from a query from the Sequelize ORM. Currently it logs a 404 error "GET /api/users 404 3ms". As you may have heard the documentation for Sequelize is pretty limited and I've been searching github repo after tutorial and none have worked thus far, so I'd thought I'd ask here.

A small excerpt (code on https://github.com/NatuMyers/A.M.E.N.SQL-Stack):

```
// VARS -----------------------------
var express        = require('express')
  , bodyParser     = require('body-parser')
  , errorHandler   = require('errorhandler')
  , methodOverride = require('method-override')
  , morgan         = require('morgan')
  , http           = require('http')
  , path           = require('path')
  , db             = require('./models')

var router = require('express').Router();
var app = express()

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(methodOverride())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// SEQUELIZE MODELS 
var userVar     = require('./models/user');

// dev only
 if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
      app.use(errorHandler())
}

// Make db, and make it listen 
db
.sequelize
.sync()
.complete(function(err) {
    if (err) {
    throw err
    } else {
              http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
              console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'))
            })
    }
    })

// HTTP GET endpoints
module.exports = function() {

  router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
      res.json({ message: 'This works at localhost:3000/api but getting a list of users is a pain :(' });
  });

  // question
  router.get('/users', function(req, res, next){
      res.json(/* I need to make sequelize send a part of the User db here. */);
  });

return router;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved on from this by using Epilogue.js (in a vanilla way).

I added models INLINE with Sequelize (I wasted lots of time trying to import models), then add any middle ware and create the restful api based on the syntax below.

```
// 1. ADD SEQUELIZE MODELS ---- ---- ---- ----
var database = new Sequelize('raptroopdb', 'root', 'strongpassword');

var Employee = database.define('Employee', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    hireDate: Sequelize.DATE
});

// Add Account model with foreign key constraint to Employee
var Account = database.define('Account', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    managerId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,

        references: {
            // This is a reference to model Employee
            model: Employee,

            // This is the column name of the referenced model
            key: 'id',

        }
    }
});

// 2. ROOM FOR MIDDLEWARE to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('In server.js');

    // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
    next();
});

// Initialize epilogue
epilogue.initialize({
    app: app,
    sequelize: database
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/public/index.html');
});



// 3. Create REST resource
var employeeResource = epilogue.resource({
    model: Employee,
    endpoints: ['/api/employees', '/api/employees/:id']
});

var acctResource = epilogue.resource({
    model: Account,
    endpoints: ['/api/accounts', '/api/accounts/:id']
});

// Create database and listen
database
    .sync({
        force: false
    })
    .then(function() {
        app.listen(port, function() {
            console.log('listening at %s', port);
        });
    });
```